# Pick up value from textbox after receiving it on the submit page in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, submit, asp.net

I have two aspx pages. First one has two hidden input fields as this:

```
<input id="ad" name="ad" type="hidden" value="<%=Request.QueryString("ad") & "" %>" />
<input id="bd" name="bd" type="hidden" value="<%=Request.QueryString("bd") & "" %>" />
```

Now when this lands on the next page, I need to pick up these values, so basically:

```
dim a1 as integer = 0, b1 as integer = 0
a1 = ad.value
b1 = bd.value
```

I'm new to this, so can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

On the code file for the page that sends the values, declare global variables, then in your submit, set the values for the variables to whatever was entered on the form.

Then, in the page that receives the info, do the following:

```
Public Class Page2
Public Page1 As Page1 ' This is the global declaration that allows you to get values from the previous page
Public a1 As Integer = Page1.a1
Public b1 As Integer = Page1.b1
```

HTH